# How to map two positive integers to a unique integer?

Tags: c++, c

I need to find a unique integer given two integers. That is, given two integers x and y..I want to find a function f...which maps these integers uniquely to another integer z. That is,
        z=f(x,y)

Here x=64 bit integer and y=64 bit integer. I want to map these numbers to z such it is again a 64 bit integer.

I tried Cantors pairing function, but Cantors pairing function returns to me a 'z' which is 128 bit as there is a multiplication involved in Cantors pairing function. I do not want z to map to 128 bit as modern computers have processing limitation of only upto 64 bit.

Is there some way out. A little bit of collision is acceptable to me.

Comment: Do you need some help writing a C function that can take two 64-bit integers, and then return a 64-bit integer?

Comment: Ask yourself a simpler question first: Is there a function that maps any combination of two bits uniquely to one single bit?

Comment: I want to write a C function that takes two 64-bit integers and maps them to a unique 64 bit integer

Comment: Suggested Hash: `x ^ y ^ MagicBigPrime`, else I suspect you are SOL.  See [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: You can't do this. There are 2^64 x 2^64 possible input combinations - that's 2^128 in total. You can't map this to a single 64 bit output without a significant amount of collision.

Comment: This probably goes against laws of entropy as you cannot take 128 bit (64 + 64 bit) and map them to a unique 64 bit, at least not without information loss -- so your requirement of mapping them to a unique 64 bit value is impossible.   You will have to put some restrictions on your 2*64 bit input .. like for example they cannot exceed 32 bit each... or that the output does not have to be unique for all combinations of input.

Comment: I don't get the question, do you need a unique output only? do you need a reversible function? I don't know may be using raw logical operators would help ...

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do that for the whole range of 64 bit integer, then this is impossible.

There are `2^64 * 2^64 = 2^128` possible inputs for your function, but you have only `2^64` different outputs, which means that there have to be at least `2^64` numbers mapped to the same integer which is far more than `a little bit of collision`

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially looking for a 64bit hash function. Here is a list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this function 'boiler-plate' will help?

```
unsigned long long f(
      unsigned long long x,
      unsigned long long y
      )
   {
   /** many options here, including those in link provided by @xosp7tom's answer... **/
   return(x*y);
   }
```